# Merging JSON and an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have the below json and object.

```
acctData = [
{
"acctNum": "AAA - 1234",
"user": "Alice"
},
{
"acctNum": "AAA - 5231",
"user": "Bob"
},
{
"acctNum": "AAA - 9921",
"user": "Alice"
},
{
"acctNum": "AAA - 8191",
"user": "Alice"
}
];
balance = {
"AAA - 1234": 4593.22,
"AAA - 9921": 0,
"AAA - 5231": 232142.5,
"AAA - 8191": 4344
};
```

I want to merge it to get the below response

```
[{acctNum: "AAA - 1234", user: "Alice", balance: 4593.22},
{acctNum: "AAA - 5231", user: "Bob", balance: 232142.5},
{acctNum: "AAA - 9921", user: "Alice", balance: 0},
{acctNum: "AAA - 8191", user: "Alice", balance: 4344}]

function myFunction() {
    for (var key in acctData) {
       for(var name in balance) {
         if ( acctData[key].acctNum === name) {
          acctData[key]['balance']= balance[acctData[key].acctNum];
          break;
         }
       } 
    }
}
```

I this is a correct approach to do it using vanilla javascript or there is more efficient way?

Comment: Correct and efficient are not necessarily the same thing. Which are you asking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by simply using a map.

```js
const acctData = [
 {
 "acctNum": "AAA - 1234",
 "user": "Alice"
 },
 {
 "acctNum": "AAA - 5231",
 "user": "Bob"
 },
 {
 "acctNum": "AAA - 9921",
 "user": "Alice"
 },
 {
 "acctNum": "AAA - 8191",
 "user": "Alice"
 }
];

const balance = {
 "AAA - 1234": 4593.22,
 "AAA - 9921": 0,
 "AAA - 5231": 232142.5,
 "AAA - 8191": 4344
};

const newAccount = acctData.map(acc => {
 acc.balance = balance[acc.acctNum];
 return acc;
});

console.log(newAccount);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring):

```
let result = acctData.map(({acctNum, user}) => ({acctNum, user, balance: balance[acctNum]}));
```

```js
let acctData = [
{
"acctNum": "AAA - 1234",
"user": "Alice"
},
{
"acctNum": "AAA - 5231",
"user": "Bob"
},
{
"acctNum": "AAA - 9921",
"user": "Alice"
},
{
"acctNum": "AAA - 8191",
"user": "Alice"
}
];
let balance = {
"AAA - 1234": 4593.22,
"AAA - 9921": 0,
"AAA - 5231": 232142.5,
"AAA - 8191": 4344
};

let result = acctData.map(({acctNum, user}) => ({acctNum, user, balance: balance[acctNum]}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), try this

```js
let acctData = [ { "acctNum": "AAA - 1234", "user": "Alice" }, { "acctNum": "AAA - 5231", "user": "Bob" }, { "acctNum": "AAA - 9921", "user": "Alice" }, { "acctNum": "AAA - 8191", "user": "Alice" } ];
let balance = { "AAA - 1234": 4593.22, "AAA - 9921": 0, "AAA - 5231": 232142.5, "AAA - 8191": 4344 };

console.log(acctData.map(res=>({...res, 'balance': balance[res.acctNum] })))
```